# How to remove formulas from sheet but keep their calculated values

Tags: vba, excel

Can you please let me know how I can remove all formulas from a sheet but keep the results of calculations in excel VBA?

I have a sheet called map which has lots of calculation columns there now I would like to remove all of this formulas but still keep the result to save into a new sheet.

Comment: `Sheet.UsedRange = Sheet.UsedRange`?

Comment: You don't need VBA for this :) Cells - Copy - Paste Special Values

Comment: I'd echo Siddarth.  If you need to do it programmatically, record the macro for Select All > Paste Special... > Values.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for reply, I am getting this sheets alot so no time to do this things manualy

Comment: @rdhs: That is a wrong way. The data from the entire sheet will get deleted. I guess you wanted to say `Sheet.UsedRange.Value = Sheet.UsedRange.Value`

Comment: Ok, this didnt work! all I want to do is removing all formulas from a entire a sheet but keep the values. How i can do this by recording a Macro? I can copy and paste some where else but this is not what i am looking for

Comment: @Behseini: If you want to use VBA then see my last comment.

Comment: @Siddharth, Thanks but how I can call this from a Module? I mean I have a sheet which is like  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS") so how I can use the  Sheet.UsedRange.Value = Sheet.UsedRange.Value after that? thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, the easiest way to remove formulas from spreadsheets is to use this tool: http://goo.gl/EEuxV8

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Way 1** (Courtesy @rdhs)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")

    ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
```

**Way 2** `Using Copy - PasteSpecial - Values`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")

    With ws.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Way 3** Using `SpecialCells`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Value = rng.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, just a quick question is there another way to select the sheet instead of Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS") I mean I want to work with this sheet but sometimes the name is a little bit diffrent based on people how sunmitting like DTM_GIS or DTM GIS. so can I select the sheet based on number or activity?

Comment: Use the code name of the sheet. That ways no matter what the sheet name is, it will work. See [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214189%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [THIS](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm)

Comment: It should be noted that the first method requires manual calculation mode.