# Copy All values VBA script failing

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA script that copies all data in a whole workbook as pastes as values, then saves as a new workbook, thus removing all formulas.

Here is my code:

```
Sub MakeAllVals()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    With wSheet
        .UsedRange.Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
Next wSheet

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```

I'm getting a runtime error 1004 on the .PasteSpecial xlValues command but I can't work out why.

How can I accomplish the goal of pasting all data as values and saving as a new workbook?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671795/how-to-remove-formulas-from-sheet-but-keep-their-calculated-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to paste to a range in the new sheet. Currently you are not pasting within the new book and you are not pasting within a range.

```
Sub MakeAllVals()
    Dim oldBook As Workbook, oldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newBook As Workbook, newSheet As Worksheet

    Set oldBook = ThisWorkbook      ' Set to the formula workbook you want to copy from
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add     ' Make the new workbook you want only values in

    For Each oldSheet In oldBook.Sheets   ' Loop through all of the sheets in the formula book
        Set newSheet = newBook.Sheets.Add ' Make a new sheet in the newbook to add the values to

        newSheet.Name = oldSheet.Name & " Values" 
        oldSheet.UsedRange.Copy                   
        newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues ' Paste in a range on the new sheet as Values
    Next oldSheet

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ' Show Save As Dialog window
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close just have to move UsedRange up next to wSheet

```
Sub MakeAllVals()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
    End With
Next wSheet

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
End Sub
```