# ClosedXML read row with VLOOKUP formula

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

im currently working on a project that reads data from excel using closedXML but im having errors with my code because the excel cells have vlookup formulas in it. is there a way for closedxml to read row values with vlookup formulas? Thanks!

this is where i get the "Syntax Error" error:

```
if (rowValue.Cell(colnum).HasFormula)
{
    ((IDictionary<String, Object>)item)[field] = rowValue.Cell(colnum).Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `develop` branch of http://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML now supports `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the **ValueCached** gave the right text. (ClosedXML_v0.76.0.0)

```
IXLCell JobCell = row.Cells().Where(item => item.Address.ColumnLetter == "B").FirstOrDefault(); }
string Job = JobCell.RichText.Text;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Job))
{
   Job = JobCell.ValueCached;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML doesn't support `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` formulas. If you need them you have to implement them manually by reading the range of cells and searching for the row or column with the given value.

Answer (score 0):

As Raidri mentions VLOOKUPS are not supported in Closed XML.

See this discussion on the closedxml codebase forum for updates on VLOOKUP support in closed xml

https://closedxml.codeplex.com/discussions/569497

A suggested workaround would be to write a VBA macro for your template file to hook into the before save event, and paste special values into a hidden worksheet, and upload from there. See these links for a starter on doing that.

Pasting special values programattically in VBA - [How to remove formulas from sheet but keep their calculated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671795/how-to-remove-formulas-from-sheet-but-keep-their-calculated-values)
Hooking in to the before save event - http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/374035-visual-basic-applications-save-event.html