# How to copy a worksheet to a new worksheet but as values only?

Tags: excel, vba

I copy a worksheet "Costing Sheet" to a new worksheet.

I use this code:

```
Sub CopyPasteSheetAsValues()
    Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

There are formulas in the copied sheet that I do not need in the new worksheet. I would like to copy the worksheet into a new sheet but paste as 'values only'.

I also have the code below that can copy and paste the worksheet but it overrides the current sheet. Instead of a new worksheet with values only, it's the same worksheet as values.

```
Sub CopyPasteSheet()
    'Copy and Paste Summary Sheet as Values
    Sheets("Costing Sheet").Cells.Copy Before:=Sheets("Comparison Job")
    Sheets("Costing Sheet").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I tried to combine the codes but was unsuccessful.

Comment: The new sheet is *probably* be called "Costing Sheet (2)". Using `Sheets("Costing Sheet (2)").UsedRange.value = Sheets("Costing Sheet (2)").UsedRange.value ` should convert all the formulas into their resulting values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that a sheet becomes the active one when it is copied from another sheet

```
Sub CopyPasteSheetAsValues()

Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Costing Sheet")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great! Wondering if it would be possible to do something similar but have range B6:F68 as values only and keep the rest of the new pasted worksheet with the formulas from the copied worksheet.

Comment: Yes just use `range("B6:F68")` instead of `usedrange`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: This works great, however for some reason some of the formatting is lost. For example superscipt text won't be superscript in the copied workbook. I wonder if there is a way around that?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672092/5629588 (Way 2) keeps all the formatting intact.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a copy with no destination will create a new workbook with the copied worksheet. Assigning the value of the range to the value of the range will get rid of the formulas.

```
Dim myNewWB as Workbook

Worksheets("Costing Sheet").Copy
Set myNewWB = ActiveWorkbook
With myNewWB.Worksheets(1)
   .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count,.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Value= _
   .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count,.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Although I wasn't looking to add the copied sheet to a new workbook this worked great and I will keep it in mind!

Comment: @icalderon - sorry, thought you said you wanted the sheet in a new workbook... I should read more carefully. <grin>